# Parsing time from the CLI in Sierra adjusted for the timezone

Tags: macos

```
$ date
Fri Nov 25 16:44:07 SGT 2016
$ date -j -f "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S" "2016-11-12T01:46:00.000000Z" +%Y%m%d%H%M
Warning: Ignoring 8 extraneous characters in date string (.000000Z)
201611120146
```

I'm in +8 hours so when I parse that UTC string with .000000Z, I want the resulting time to be `201611120946`, not `201611120146`.

I tried .%Z but that didn't work, so I am little stuck how to get this date parse to work.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible in [dateutils](http://www.fresse.org/dateutils/):

```
$ dateconv 2016-11-12T01:46:00.000000Z --zone Asia/Singapore -f '%Y%m%d%H%M'
201611120946
```

If the offset isn't known by name but rather you want 8 hours (or any other time interval) added to a UTC stamp you can use `dateadd`

```
$ dateadd 2016-11-12T01:46:00.000000Z +8h -f '%Y%m%d%H%M'
201611120946
```

Comment: Please consider mentioning that you are associated with `dateutils` and that it is not part of macOS.

Comment: Yes, that's correct, if someone could put a disclaimer in: I am the author of the software (dateutils) and it's not part of MacOS and hence has to be installed manually.  My reply solely exists because hendry privately contacted me to make me aware of this question.

Comment: Your comment is enough of a disclaimer. Thank you for sharing this project and your work; it is appreciated!